# changing the subject of p=max(x,0)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to make an equation for $x$ in a larger equation which I will simplify for the sake of this question to $p=max(x,0)$ and am stuck on this part. $max()$ here is used like the function in excel (give $x$ if $x > 0$ else give $0$)

What is the way that I could change the subject of this equation?

Answer (score 0):

If $p=0$ then we cannot tell what $x$ was (we only know $x\leq 0$).

This means the only way to "change the subject" is if we introduce an auxiliary variable, such as $q = \min(x,0)$, in which case $x=p+q$.